# Как в цикле for в массив пушить объект в котором будет по 2 значения?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, циклы

Никак не могу додуматься.

```
let content = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    content.push({i})
}
```

Получается до 5 (здесь без разницы), значит в массиве должно быть 3 объекта, в каждом по 2 значения. В последнем объекте массива естественно будет только одно значения.

Что то вроде этого в итоге:

```
[{key: value, key: value}, {key: value, key: value}, {key: value}]
```

Буду рад любой подсказке, помощи. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Распишите подробнее, какой результат вы хотите получить.

Comment: Чтобы в итоге в массиве были объекты в зависимости от числа которую мы вставим. В данном случае у меня число 5 (без разницы, хоть 10, 50). Исходя из этого, у нас в массиве будет 3 объекта, потому что 5 мы можем разделили так : 2 , 2 , 1. В первом объекте 2 ключ значения , во втором 2 ключ значения, а в 3 один. Если вас смутило мое [{key: value}] то это я просто условно так написал, здесь можно назвать как угодно ключ и значение.

Comment: Приведите пример ключа и значения. Одинаковый ключ два раза быть не может.

Comment: Те же значения из цикла можно использовать. Например [{0:0: 1:1}, {2:2, 3:3}, {4:4}] или как захотите.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let content = [];

let count = 7;

for( let i = 0; i < count; i += 2 ){
    let obj = { key1: i };
    if( i + 1 < count ) obj.key2 = i + 1;
    content.push(obj);
}

console.log(content);
```

Comment: Вау, спасибо больше! Только я не понял этот момент: i+=2

Comment: Это обычный оператор "присваивания со сложением". Наращивает переменную на 2. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment

Comment: Всё, понял! Спасибо за уделенное время!